# Deprecated Binding in viewmodel

Tags: c#, xamarin, data-binding, xamarin.forms

fellows. The old method of Property.Created is deprecated and I now need to use Property.Created() but I've been unable to update this class to the new standard. I've attempted to check the forums, the offical post but I just can't see how I can convert this code to the new standard.

```
public ImageGallery()
{
    this.Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal;

    _imageStack = new StackLayout
    {
        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal
    };

    this.Content = _imageStack;
}

public IList<View> Children
{
    get
    {
        return _imageStack.Children;
    }
}
```

Deprecated

```
public static BindableProperty ItemsSourcePrsoperty =  BindableProperty.Create<ImageGallery, IList>(
    view => view.ItemsSource,
    default(IList),
    BindingMode.TwoWay,
    propertyChanging: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) => {
        ((ImageGallery) bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanging();
    },
    propertyChanged: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) => {
        ((ImageGallery) bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanged(bindableObject, oldValue, newValue);
    }
);
```

This is how I attempted to upgrade it

```
public static BindableProperty ItemsSourcePrsoperty = BindableProperty.Create<ImageGallery, IList>(
    view => view.ItemsSource,
    default(IList),
    BindingMode.TwoWay,
    propertyChanging: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) =>
    {
        ((ImageGallery)bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanging();
    },
    propertyChanged: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) =>
    {
        ((ImageGallery)bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanged(bindableObject, oldValue, newValue);
    }
);
```

However, got a plethora of compile error for this. "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type"

```
public IList ItemsSource
{
    get
    {
        return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
    }
    set
    {

        SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }
}

void ItemsSourceChanging()
{
    if (ItemsSource == null)
        return;
}


void ItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
{
    if (ItemsSource == null)
        return;

    var notifyCollection = newValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
    if (notifyCollection != null)
    {
        notifyCollection.CollectionChanged += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.NewItems != null)
            {
                if (args.NewItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (var newItem in args.NewItems)
                    {
                        var view = (View)ItemTemplate.CreateContent();
                        var bindableObject = view as BindableObject;
                        if (bindableObject != null)
                            bindableObject.BindingContext = newItem;
                        _imageStack.Children.Add(view);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                _imageStack.Children.Clear();
                foreach (var Item in ItemsSource)
                {
                    var view = (View)ItemTemplate.CreateContent();
                    var bindableObject = view as BindableObject;
                    if (bindableObject != null)
                        bindableObject.BindingContext = Item;
                    _imageStack.Children.Add(view);
                }
            }
        };
```

Deprecated

```
public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedItemProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create<ImageGallery, object>(
        view => view.SelectedItem,
        null,
        BindingMode.TwoWay,
        propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            ((ImageGallery)bindable).UpdateSelectedIndex();
        }
    );
```

Deprecated / Generics no longer supported

```
public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedIndexProperty =
    BindableProperty.Create<ImageGallery, int>(
        carousel => carousel.SelectedIndex,
        0,
        BindingMode.TwoWay,
        propertyChanged: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            ((ImageGallery)bindable).UpdateSelectedItem();
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using the other overload instead. For example:

```
public class ImageGallery : ScrollView
{
    public static BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(ItemsSource), typeof(IList), typeof(ImageGallery), BindingMode.TwoWay,
        propertyChanging: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            ((ImageGallery)bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanging();
        },
        propertyChanged: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) =>
        {
            ((ImageGallery)bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanged(bindableObject, oldValue, newValue);
        }
    );

    public IList ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    void ItemsSourceChanging()
    {
    }

    void ItemsSourceChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
    }
}
```